# AVD Manager appears different

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

My AVD Manager appears like this:

[image: Mine]

But I need to appear like this:

[image: NeedThis]

How do I fix this?

Comment: The reference screenshot is an older version. Updated versions don't look the same anymore. There's no "fix" for this.

Comment: Why would you need it to look like that?

Comment: To comment on an answer, click the "add comment" link beneath the answer, not the "edit" link. To ask a fresh StackOverflow question, click the "Ask Question" button in the upper-right corner, not the "edit" link on an existing answer.

Comment: ^ Hope you ain't talking to me. I normally just put a quick comment in when it's not a _real_ answer. I'll up you answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> How do I fix this?

You don't. Use what you have, which is the newer version. If you are encountering problems in interpreting instructions for the old version and how to apply them to the newer version, feel free to ask specific StackOverflow questions about that.